# Adding a sort algo to my program break functions before it

Tags: c, sorting

So I wrote a sorting algorithm (I'm still learning so it's probably a little mess).

Now when I add it to my **main.c**, it breaks the functions before it without even starting, and it makes no sense.

The sorting function is:

```
void ordinaAlfabeticamente(RecordSoggetto *elenco, int nElementi) {
    printf("avviando sorting");
    int i, j, comparatore;
    RecordSoggetto *copia = (RecordSoggetto *)malloc(sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
    _Bool isStillSorting = true;
    while (isStillSorting) {
        isStillSorting = false;
        for (i = 1; i < nElementi; i++) {
            memcpy(copia, &elenco[i], sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
            j = i - 1;
            comparatore = strcmp(elenco[j].cognome, copia->cognome);
            if (comparatore == 0) {
                comparatore = strcmp(elenco[j].nome, copia->nome);
            }
            while (j > 0 && comparatore) {
                isStillSorting = true;
                memcpy(&elenco[j + 1], &elenco[j], sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
                j--;
                memcpy(&elenco[j + 1], copia, sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the main:

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    VD database;
    caricaDati(&database, "../Database.dat");
    ordinaAlfabeticamente(database.v, database.nElementi);
    stampaElencoCriminali(database.v, database.nElementi);

    inizializzaVettoreDinamico(&database);

    return 0;
}
```

Now the interesting part, if the function `ordinaAlfabeticamente` is in the main the function `caricaDati` just gives up at the first line, like, literally.

caricaDati:

```
void caricaDati(VD *dati, char *nomefile) {
    printf("avviando carica dati\n");
    FILE *fp = apriFile(nomefile, "rb"); //apriFile is just open with control
    printf("file aperto");
    fread(&dati->nElementi, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    printf("letto numero elementi");
    dati->v = (RecordSoggetto *)malloc(dati->nElementi * sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
    fread(dati->v, sizeof (RecordSoggetto), dati->nElementi, fp);
    printf("letto criminali");
    chiudiFile(fp);
};
```

The `printf` are for control and just the first one starts, I also tried to put a printf in the function `apriFile` but they don't start, so I'm assuming that the function just dies after the first `printf`.

To be more specific, once I start the program it just prints `avviando carica dati\n` and enters an infinite loop.

HOWEVER

If I just delete the call for `ordinaAlfabeticamente` in the main I get no problems.

Should I make something js-like to wait for the `caricaDati` to finish before the sorting function starts?

I TRIED TO TRANSLATE EVERYTHING TO ENGLISH TO MAKE IT MORE READABLE:

So I've wrote a sorting algo (I'm still learning so it's probably a little mess).

Now when I add it to my main.c it breaks the functions before it without even starting, and it makes no sense.

The sorting function is:

```
void sortAlphabetically(RecordSoggetto *elementList, int nElements) {
    printf("start sorting");
    int i, j, comparatore;
    RecordSoggetto *copy = (RecordSoggetto *)malloc(sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
    _Bool isStillSorting = true;
    while (isStillSorting) {
        isStillSorting = false;
        for (i = 1; i < nElements; i++) {
            memcpy(copy, &elementList[i], sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
            j = i - 1;
            comparatore = strcmp(elementList[j].surname, copy->surname);
            if (comparatore == 0) {
                comparatore = strcmp(elementList[j].name, copy->name);
            }
            while (j > 0 && comparatore) {
                isStillSorting = true;
                memcpy(&elementList[j + 1], &elementList[j], sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
                j--;
                memcpy(&elementList[j + 1], copy, sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the main:

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    VD database;
    loadData(&database, "../Database.dat");
    sortAlphabetically(database.v, database.nElementi);
    printElementList(database.v, database.nElementi);

    inizializzaVettoreDinamico(&database); // not relevant

    return 0;
}
```

Now the interesting part, if the function `sortAlphabetically` is in the main the function `loadData` just gives up at the first line, like, literally.

loadData:

```
void loadData(VD *data, char *filename) {
    printf("starting load data\n");
    FILE * fp = openFile(filename, "rb"); //apriFile is just open with control
    printf("file opened");
    fread(&data->nElements, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    printf("read number of elements");
    data->v = (RecordSoggetto *)malloc(data->nElements * sizeof(RecordSoggetto));
    fread(data->v, sizeof (RecordSoggetto), data->nElements, fp);
    printf("read elements");
    closeFile(fp);
};
```

The printf are for control and just the first one starts, I also tried to put a printf in the function `apriFile` but they don't start, so I'm assuming that the function just dies after the first printf.

To be more specific, once I start the program it just print `start load data\n` and enters an infinite loop.

HOWEVER

If I just delete the call for sortAlphabetically in the main I get no problems.

Should I make something js-like to wait for the `loadData` to finish before the sorting function starts?

Comment: camelcase and `_Bool` , first time I've seen these. Also, I'm not fluent with your language , is it possible for you to resubmit / comment the code with english, not to be rude, I just have trouble keeping track of the variables , I too only know english as my second language. Until then , i'd suggest a debugger :)

Comment: Are you sure the file exists and the path is right?

Comment: Notes : 1) If this is C, casting a `void *` returned by malloc is not necessary . 2) Can you provide an Minimum Reproducible Example ? Since I cant quite read the code , maybe I can run it to find out. 3) `printf()` prints to `stdout` which is line buffered and may not print until a `\n` is encountered .Use `stderr` or add a `\n`. 4) Subjective , but I find it easier to follow indentation if it is `if \n {` rather than `if{ ...` , and it makes it easier to follow the code.

Comment: @AnAnt: camelCase is uncommon in C, but perfectly fine. `_Bool` is a keyword since C99 (see [C99 6.2.5p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.5p2) and [C99 6.4.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.4.1)).

Comment: @pmg I am aware that both are very much valid, was just amused to see them for the first time .

Comment: `FILE * fp = apriFile(nomefile, "rb"); //apriFile is just open with control` Since this is the line where control seems to stop from what you are saying, is it possible that `nomefile` is uninitialised / has an invalid value or `apriFile()` fails ? AFAIK `../Database.dat` seems like some sort of mistake with the two `..` ?

Comment: Further, you seem to do `VD database;` and then `loadData( &database ...` . In this code, variable `database` of type `VD` need not exist yet (as it is defined, but not assigned anything) and certainly has a garbage value , and so passing a pointer to it may not be a great idea, not sure. BTW , **Thanks for the translation** .

Comment: @AnAnt I tried to translate everything in English for better readability(it was in italian for school purpose), the function apriFile doesn't even start, so it's not the control (the control would exit with 255), the path with the ../ is because I'm operating with ubuntu, and, without the sorting function in the program it works just fine :( I'll try to fix the print now with the \n, yep, the file exists and the path is right, removing the function to sort from the main fix everything :( I'm so confused, it looks like nothing work if the sorting function is in the main

Comment: @Pepe get back after fixing the `printf` , since it **WILL NOT** print without an EOL (*end of line*) very often , not just because of the program crashing or such. While I still did not understand why you have two dots, it seems like that is intentional from the above.

Comment: Note that this is still **not an MRE** as the given code is insufficient to compile a binary that replicates your problem. Given that this is just for school, this shouldn't be too hard to provide here (you *aren't* grappling with proprietary/ someone else's non-free code that isn't working). This would likely make this all much easier. Also, since your code seems to compile, why not **try to enable as many warnings as you can ?** Further, it's not quite clear (nor *can* it be if you just describe in words) what the output is. `Ctrl +C` the console output and `Ctrl + V` it here.

Comment: **Further Notes :** 1) `void loadData(VD *data, char *filename){...};` why the *`;`* at the end of a function definition ? 2) None of your `printf()` calls after `printf("starting load data\n");` have a newline. And you say that after this line, you see an infinite loop. This means that the other `printf`s have not printed due to no EOL , and you have likely gotten stuck in the `while()` loop (one of them ) in your sort function.

Comment: @AnAnt Wow for the print statements it really was the missing \n, so now it just get stuck in an infinite loop with the sorting algo, That makes surely more sense than it breaking the other functions ahahah thank you for the input! Now its only the sorting function that it's broken

Comment: Absolutely, your'e welcome. Buffered `stdout` can be a devil, use `stderr` in `fprintf()` when debugging. It writes each character *as it comes*. I still request you to post an **MRE**, and results of compiling *with all warnings*

Comment: Are you sure the database exists the way you are reading it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sorting algorithm is incorrect, it does not swap the records in the right place.

Here is a modified version:

```
void ordinaAlfabeticamente(RecordSoggetto *elenco, int nElementi) {
    _Bool isStillSorting = true;
    while (isStillSorting) {
        isStillSorting = false;
        for (int i = 1; i < nElementi; i++) {
            int comparatore = strcmp(elenco[i - 1].cognome, elenco[i].cognome);
            if (comparatore > 0 ||
                (comparatore == 0 && strcmp(elenco[i - 1].nome, elenco[i].nome) > 0)) {
                // swap records that are out of order
                RecordSoggetto tmp = elenco[i - 1];
                elenco[i - 1] = elenco[i];
                elenco[i] = tmp;
                isStillSorting = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using English for identifiers is indeed more readable and easier to share with foreigners:

```
void sortAlphabetically(RecordSoggetto *elementList, int nElements) {
    _Bool isStillSorting = true;
    while (isStillSorting) {
        isStillSorting = false;
        for (int i = 1; i < nElements; i++) {
            int cmp = strcmp(elementList[i - 1].cognome, elementList[i].cognome);
            if (cmp > 0 ||
                (cmp == 0 && strcmp(elementList[i - 1].nome, elementList[i].nome) > 0)) {
                // swap records that are out of order
                RecordSoggetto tmp = elementList[i - 1];
                elementList[i - 1] = elementList[i];
                elementList[i] = tmp;
                isStillSorting = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Old timers (such as I) will contend that shorter names for local variables actually increase readability. I let you be the judge for your own environment:

```
void sortAlphabetically(RecordSoggetto *array, int n) {
    int done = 0;
    while (!done) {
        done = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            int cmp = strcmp(array[i - 1].cognome, array[i].cognome);
            if (cmp > 0 || (cmp == 0 && strcmp(array[i - 1].nome, array[i].nome) > 0)) {
                // swap records that are out of order
                RecordSoggetto tmp = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = tmp;
                done = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, camelcase is worse than division by `*b` where `b=NULL` ;) And newbies should really put the braces on the next line

Comment: @AnAnt: no they should not because they make silly mistakes such as `for (i = 0; i < n; i++);\n{\n    /* why is this code always executed but only once? */\n}`.

Comment: Well that truly is a *silly mistake* and I dont see what it has to do with placement of braces, while placing them in a new line is more readable.

Comment: Not really silly, just a typo and the line ends with a `;` which is not eye catching. I have seen examples on this site too many times. This spurious `;` is much easier to spot when it lies between the `)` and the `{` and also much less likely to have been typed there. Regarding readability, spreading the code on more lines does not always improve readability.

Comment: Alright, i suppose this is subjective and we'll have to agree to disagree. I find code to  be a maze without { on the next line, even though in my early phases I would place it in the same line . I've really never has the error of placing a ; after the loop unintentioanlly , and if i did, clang would tell me, but I suppose your points have merits

Comment: Readability is subjective indeed, unlike typos and bugs which are facts. Think of the trailing `{` as the C equivalent to the trailing `:` in Python flow control statements, which many a programmer consider a *clean and readable* language. In my experience, reading a program is **much** more difficult than writing it, by an order of magnitude. Every attempt should be made to improve readability, including horizontal spacing and a good and consistent choice of naming conventions and presentation style.